# Is it possible to export Silverlight canvas to HTML with scripts

Tags: jquery, html, silverlight, drag-and-drop

In one of our application we have to implement item drag/drop functionality on the page and later export that page to HTML along with JQuery and CSS.

I would like to use Silverlight as my application development to give a greater user experience. Like to add item drag and drop facility from one item container to another.

But the final thing we want to implement is, that once we are ready with our drag and drop on canvas/page we would like to export that canvas/page to pure html along with Jquery and CSS.

So the question is: Is it possible to export canvas to html? If yes please provide sample code.

Comment: If you need it to be in html and css and javascript why not just start out that way?

Comment: @tam i like to use the Silverlight which give powerfull user interactions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you want the end-result of some Silverlight operations to be displayed using HTML without using Silverlight.

If that is correct the only simple option that occurs to me is: Render your canvas to a PNG on the client, send it back to the server, and serve it up as an image in HTML.

There are lots of how-to's so I would suggest simply Googling: [http://www.google.co.uk/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=silverlight+how+to+export+a+canvas+to+a+bitmap&safe=active](http://www.google.co.uk/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=silverlight%20how%20to%20export%20a%20canvas%20to%20a%20bitmap&safe=active)

If you are actually wanting to do something else (e.g. generating interactive HTML content) then please clarify your question.

Comment: thaks for your response but i m looking for canvas to html not bitmap. thanks again for your response.

Comment: Nothing in the Canvas (or UIElements) translates directly to anything in HTML. Best rethink your design. Sorry.

Comment: Thanks again i just want a logic which could help me to solve such problem.